# ngx-errors and angular6: Can´t resolve rxjs/Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to create an app with Angular 6 and using NGX-Erros module. I already updated rxjs imports to this:

```
import { Observable, Subject, pipe,of  } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeUntil, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And I still get this error : 
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ultimate/ngxerrors/src/ngxerror.directive.js   Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `ngx-errors` library is not up-to-dated with the recent breaking changes in [**RxJS 6**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-7) (**deep imports** part), check [**here**](https://github.com/selem1/ngx-errors/blob/master/src/ngxerror.directive.ts#L3) you'll see the old way to import, and that is what the output console tells you exaclty since it is pointing on your installed `Rxjs` version (mentioned in your package.json).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know any library to help with reactive forms error messages?

Comment: Sorry no, but as a workaround download that project and made your changes till it will suits you , then change your imports to refer on the local already modified directives.